# How to change mouse cursor during drag and drop?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

**Background:** I have a C# winforms application. I am dragging information from one datagridview to another. For my drag over event on the destination grid, I have the following code:

```
private void grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
      if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(SelectedRecordsCollection)))
      {
          e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move; 
      }
}
```

I want to limit the drop to only be allowed when the mouse is hovered over particular rows (say, rows with an odd index number). I currently limit what I actually add to the destination grid in the dragdrop event. However, because of the above code, my cursor changes to a Move icon as soon as the mouse hovers anywhere on the destination control.

**Question:** How do I make it so that the cursor is a "Cursor.No" icon everywhere on the destination grid, except set it to the Move icon for when the mouse is over a row with an odd index?

Thank you.

**Edit:** Aseem's solution ended up working for me.

Comment: To get the "Cursor.No" effect, you will need to use "e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;". Your program seems like it will need some more complex code though to achieve the effect you want, basically, how to detect if it's on an odd row... So you might not want to use "if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(SelectedRecordsCollection)))", and change it with an if statement that detects if the row it is over is odd perhaps.

Comment: I think you need to do something in `Drag_Enter`.

Comment: I agree, @Sinatr. He most definitely has to do something in Drag_Enter like as in this answer(s): http://stackoverflow.com/a/32242472/3472690 (doesn't answer his question, but provides an example of what you said)

Comment: Drag_Enter only occurs once for the grid, so DragOver should be used.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. From msdn "The DragOver event is raised when the mouse cursor moves within the bounds of the control during a drag-and-drop operation."   My understanding is that this means the Drag over event only fires once, and that's when the mouse initially drags over the control. I need an event like OnCellMouseEnter that I could use to determine when the mouse has hovered over a new row. Then I can determine the row index. However, is it possible to change the effect of the drag to DragDropEffects.None when I'm in another event like OnCellMouseEnter?

Comment: **UPDATE** Now that I'm reading that msdn quote again, I see that it says when the mouse moves. I will need to test this out Aseem's answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

Get the row index using HitTest. Try this, not tested though -

```
private void grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the row index of the item the mouse is below. 
    Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);
    if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell) {
        e.Effect = (hit.RowIndex%2 == 0)  //move when odd index, else none
            ? DragDropEffects.None
            : DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! As per my comment above, my impression is that DragOver only fires once when the mouse enters the control. But what happens during the drag when I move my mouse from one row to hover over a different one?  **Edit:** Now that I'm reading that msdn quote again, I see that it says when the mouse moves. I will need to test this out. Thank you.