# Keep the cursor at default shape during drag and drop operation in windows forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a simple drag and drop operation in windows forms. Whenever I start the operation the cursor changes shape. I know this is directly related to the `DragDropEffects` and I can't find an option that results in the default cursor. Can anybody help? Here is the code:

```
a.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(ButtonDown);
a.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(ButtonDragEnter);
a.AllowDrop = true;
```

and here are the functions:

```
private void ButtonDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
    ButtonClick(sender, e);
    p.DoDragDrop(p.BackColor, DragDropEffects.All);
}

private void ButtonDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Data.GetFormats();
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

    Color c = new Color();
    c = (Color) e.Data.GetData(c.GetType());
    ButtonClick(sender, e,c);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Winforms - change cursor icon of mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902327/c-sharp-winforms-change-cursor-icon-of-mouse)

Comment: I already know how to change the cursor to default cursor, but if I change the cursor before the drag and drop operation it doesn't do anything. In short, when should I change the cursor to the default one and how often?

Comment: Please review this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391655/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-during-drag-and-drop

Comment: this answers part of the question, and the first post another part. In the DragDropEffects there is no option for default cursor. How do I change the cursor type specifically to the default one during a drag and drop operation?

Comment: The default normally depends on what window or control is crossed while the user moves the mouse across it.  That can no longer work since mouse events are now directed to the D+D plumbing and not the hovered window.  So you probably did not mean "default cursor".  Change it to anything you want with the GiveFeedback event, avoid intentionally confuzzling the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok answered my own question here:

You first need to add an event to giveFeedBack:

```
  a.GiveFeedback += new GiveFeedbackEventHandler(DragSource_GiveFeedback);
```

and here is the feedback function:

```
private void DragSource_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
    }
```